# How to make tcpdump display only source IP, destination IP, ports and timestamps

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, tcpdump

I am running tcpdump to track traffic on 2 interfaces, one input and one output. The sole purpose is to measure the latency between the time when the input interface receives incoming TCP traffic and the time when the output interface sends out UDP traffic.

Because I need to do this measurement hundreds times, I like to redirect the output to a file and write a simple script to parse the timestamps.

Currently this is my command: `tcpdump -i any  -v "tcp or udp"   -ttttt` | tee log

It works, but I wonder if I could further trim its output (a snippet):

```
 00:00:00.000000 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 28712, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.10.30.6.38574 > 10.10.30.161.81: Flags [S], cksum 0x55bd (correct), seq 1010316358, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1402655839 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7],  lis=
 00:00:00.000035 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 15035, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.10.30.161.81 > 10.10.30.6.38574: Flags [S.], cksum 0x50e9 (incorrect -> 0xa4d3), seq 3593868966, ack 1010316359, win 4380, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,TS val 1402655838 ecr 1402655839,sackOK,eol], length 0 out
 00:00:00.000438 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 28713, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
```

You can see two things:

1. IP addresses, source and destination, are at different line from timestamp.
2. There are still a lot of info I do not care

So my question are:

1. is there a way to render tcpdump to display timestamp at the same line as source/destination IP addresses?
2. Can I cut further the output?

**[UPDATE]**
Currently I settle on the following shell command solution. Still curious about my questions though.

Use this command to look for the first incoming TCP packet:

```
$>grep -A 1 TCP  /tmp/junk  | head -n 2
```

And this for the first outgoing UDP:

```
$> grep -A 1 UDP  /tmp/junk  | head -n 2
```

Comment: Have you tried `-q`? Otherwise, judging from a quick scan of the manpage, the textual format doesn't seem to be configurable in detail. So the options are (1) post-process (like you have done), (2) write your own dumper.

Comment: If `tshark` is an option for you, you can get much more finer control with its output than with `tcpdump`'s I think.